# Lenovo Z570 Windows 7 Wireless LAN and VPN

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, drivers, vpn

I have reinstalled my Windows 7 and a few drivers. I can now connect to network through a wired LAN but not a wireless one. I tired to install a few drivers but they didn't work. They are :
[Intel Wireless WiFi Link Driver](http://support.lenovo.com/us/zh/products/Laptops-and-netbooks/IdeaPad-Z-Series-laptops/IdeaPad-Z570/downloads/DS010593)
[Wireless Lan Driver](http://support.lenovo.com/us/zh/products/Laptops-and-netbooks/IdeaPad-Z-Series-laptops/IdeaPad-Z570/downloads/DS011096)

In my device manager, I can only see Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller under Network adapters. The Open Network and Sharing Center only shows me I am connecting to a wired network, but cannot detect any wireless one. Neither can I do VPN right now.

Did I incorrectly install the wrong drivers? If yes, which other driver should I install?

Thanks everyone.

Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you can download this 
https://drp.su/index.htm

offline version

uninstall all you wiresslan drivers and install it using offline driver pack

but stay focus and care on  unsolicited  programs like chrome in Russian language :)

Comment: Thanks Przemon. It works perfectly. I will definitely recommend this to my friends.